# Spring Boot 2.0.4 + Thymeleaf 3.0.9: Could not initialize class HTMLTemplateParser

Tags: java, macos, spring-boot, web-applications, thymeleaf

I am trying to run a basic webapp using Spring Boot with Maven and Thymeleaf.

This is my environment:

- MacOS High Sierra 10.13.6 (the latest version)
- Java 1.8 (which should be compatible)
- Spring Boot 2.0.4 (imported with Maven)
- Thymeleaf (imported with Maven)
- Embedded Tomcat

My problem is that when I try to run my demo application in the embedded Tomcat webserver, I get the following error:

> **Whitelabel Error Page** 
>   This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
>
> Wed Aug 15 17:03:07 CEST 2018 There was an unexpected error
>   (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
>   org/attoparser/config/ParseConfiguration

Checking the console, this is the exception stacktrace:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.attoparser.config.ParseConfiguration  at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_60]    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
>     at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_60]    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
>     at
>   org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.HTMLTemplateParser.(HTMLTemplateParser.java:43)
>   ~[thymeleaf-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]  at
>   org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.(TemplateManager.java:117)
>   ~[thymeleaf-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]  at
>   org.thymeleaf.EngineConfiguration.initialize(EngineConfiguration.java:137)
>   ~[thymeleaf-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]  at
>   org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.initialize(TemplateEngine.java:341)
>   ~[thymeleaf-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]  at
>   org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.getConfiguration(TemplateEngine.java:406)
>   ~[thymeleaf-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]  at
>   org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:255)
>   ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]  at
>   org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:187)
>   ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1325)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1069)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1008)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:866)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]  at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]    at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]  at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]    at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]    at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
>   ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]    at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109)
>   ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]    at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93)
>   ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]    at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
>   ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:800)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1471)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>   [na:1.8.0_60]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>   [na:1.8.0_60]     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]     at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_60]

Weird thing is, if I try to send another HTTP GET Request (= reload the page) after this error has occurred, I will get a different error:

> **Whitelabel Error Page** 
>   This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
>
> Wed Aug 15 16:52:35 CEST 2018 There was an unexpected error
>   (type=Internal Server Error, status=500). Could not initialize class
>   org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.HTMLTemplateParser

Here is the console output for this error too:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class
>   org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.HTMLTemplateParser    at
>   org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.(TemplateManager.java:117)
>   ~[thymeleaf-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]  at
>   org.thymeleaf.EngineConfiguration.initialize(EngineConfiguration.java:137)
>   ~[thymeleaf-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]  at
>   org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.initialize(TemplateEngine.java:341)
>   ~[thymeleaf-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]  at
>   org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.getConfiguration(TemplateEngine.java:406)
>   ~[thymeleaf-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]  at
>   org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:255)
>   ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]  at
>   org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:187)
>   ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1325)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1069)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1008)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:866)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]  at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]    at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]  at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]    at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]    at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
>   ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]    at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109)
>   ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]    at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93)
>   ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]    at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
>   ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:800)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1471)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>   [na:1.8.0_60]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>   [na:1.8.0_60]     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]     at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_60]

This second error is "stable", meaning that if I reload the page after this error has occurred, the same error occurs again.

The code of the webapp is almost literally copy-pasted from this tutorial that uses an old Spring Boot version (1.4.2).

https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-hello-world-example-thymeleaf/

All I have changed is 
 - the Spring Boot version: from 1.4.2 to 2.0.4
 - the web package: apparently Spring Boot 1.4.2 had the web package embedded inside, whereas today it doesn't. 
So I have added this dependency to the Maven pom.xml file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

If I use the 1.4.2 version, the system works fine, so I believe this is the "wrong step" I have taken.
However, all the more recent tutorials that I have found use this spring-boot-starter-web package in this way, and they all raise this error in my environment.

So I am quite puzzled.

This is my full POM file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>Demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>          
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I can't reproduce that issue, are you sure those are the only changes?

Comment: Yes, those changes in the POM file are the only changes I have done in the whole project :(
Does it work in your environment using Spring Boot 2.0.4?

Comment: yes, I just ran it, using Apache Maven 3.3.9 version and java version "1.8.0_121"

Comment: Mmm, I was using JDK 1.8.0_60. Now I have updated the JDK 1.8.0_181 but the error is still there. As for Maven, I use 3.5.4. Are you on MacOS too?

Comment: No, a GNU/Linux distro, are you using an IDE to compile-run your app or just a terminal?

Comment: I am using Eclipse with Spring Tool Suite extension installed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178095/discussion-between-jorge-l-morla-and-andrea-rossi).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, as strange as it may seem, I have solved this issue by myself.
Apparently, it was caused by the way that Eclipse and Maven had downloaded and handled file *attoparser/2.0.4.RELEASE/attoparser-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar*.
It was probably corrupted.

I'm not really sure though.

Here are the steps I followed to solve the issue.

- As it was probably an environment issue, first of all I tried to switch the project to IntelliJ CE.
  The problem was not solved (even if now the error messages were slightly different).
- Not knowing what to do, I thought that maybe the issue was tied to Spring Boot version 2.0.4. So I tried to change the Spring Boot dependency from version 2.0.4 to older ones (e.g. 2.0.3, 2.0.2 etc) in the pom.xml file.
  After this change, the Webapp would not even launch.
  I would just get **IllegalStateException: Failed to read Class-Path attribute from manifest for file attoparser/2.0.4.RELEASE/attoparser-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar*.**
  This was weird: why would the project want to use attoparser 2.0.4 (which I believe is part of Spring Boot 2.0.4) even if I specifically set the Maven pom.xml to use another Spring Boot version?
- I found online that maybe the attoparser jar file was corrupted in the Maven Cache. So I tried to invalidate all caches using the IntelliJ command, and to re-import all Maven dependencies.
  It didn't solve the issue.
- Not knowing what to do, I removed the attoparser.jar file manually with `sudo rm` and re-imported all dependencies.
  This time it worked: the webapp worked smoothly with Spring Boot 2.0.0.
- Then I tried to switch to a more recent Spring Boot version in the pom.xml re-importing the dependencies again. This time I had no issues.

So, I can only guess that Maven had downloaded a corrupted attoparser 2.0.4 jar and that for some reasons it could neither get rid of it by invalidating caches, nor could switch to other attoparser versions. So by removing it manually I may have unlocked the situation. This seems a really far-fetched explanation, though.

So I am temporarily leaving this question still open. If somebody has a clearer idea of what has happened (and of how Maven works...) I would be really grateful if you could share it here.

EDIT: Ok, since nobody is answering, I am going to close this question.
If somebody can figure a better explanation for the problem I had, please write it here :)